# Symfony 2 Doctrine 2 EntityManager config

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i'm trying to get my Doctrine CommandLine Tool working in Symfony 2 project on Windows 7 and I keep getting the same error message in console:

```
Fatal error: Call to protected Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::__construct()
from invalid context in C:\wamp\www\firstSymfonyApp\cli-config.php on line 9

Call Stack:
0.0010     239440   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\firstSymfonyApp\vendor\doctrine\orm\bin\doctrine.php:0
0.0090     621376   2. require('C:\wamp\www\firstSymfonyApp\cli-config.php') C:\wamp\www\firstSymfonyApp\vendor\doctrine\orm\bin\doctrine.php:48
```

Code of my cli-config.php file:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;
require_once 'app/bootstrap.php.cache';
$em = new \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager();
return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($em);
```

Until today, I was only using doctrine on Linux where the installation was much more simple, please help me work this out.

Comment: I am fairly confident the code you posted above was not working on linux either.  Follow this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html and use $entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);

Answer (score 0):

Error message is very clear. `EntityManager::__construct` is `protected` method therefore you can't use it outside of the class.

Check out `EntityManager::create`.

Check [this link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html) for more information about how to start with Doctrine 2.

This is probably the snippet which should be important to you right now:

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$paths = array("/path/to/entity-files");
$isDevMode = false;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => 'foo',
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

Comment: I was already using this code in my bootstrap file, the only thing wrong was $em = new \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager(); instead of $em = $entityManager; in my cli-config file. Anyway thanks man. One more stupid question: in which boostrap.php file should I store the code u pasted? I have it in my bootstrap.php.cache file and its working but that's probably wrong.

Comment: Actually you don't need to create an EntityManager on your own when using Symfony. It's all done by services.